# Trying to turn an object into an array but not entirely familiar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got an object that currently looks like this:

```
{
   name: 'name',
   type: 'type',
   fields: [
   {
      name: 'field1', value: 2
   },
   {
      name: 'field2', value: 3
   }
}
```

It's an object with an array of a different type of object inside fields. What I want to do is essentially flatten it so that I have an array with no nested arrays inside.

So I want it to look like

```
{name: 'name', type: 'type', field1: 2, field2: 3, etc...}
```

where from the fields array the name is the key to value. I don't think it's overly complex but I'm new to JavaScript and struggling to work out how to do it... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the array and create a new property for every element on the object. Then delete the property holding the array.

```
for (const field of obj.fields) {
    obj[field.name] = field.value;
}
delete obj.fields;
```